# Xamarin Studio for Mac help system doesnt work

Tags: monodevelop

Xamarin Studio (4.0 build 2003) help system doesnt work - nothing happens choosing Help->Help, also Help Pad shows structure of help catalogues but no content
I tried reinstalling without success
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug that prevents it from working on most Mac OS X versions (I think it only works on Mountain Lion or something).

It should be fixed in an upcoming release.